# Cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Predicate<int>'

Tags: c#

How to fix this?
Or, why is this error showing up. What am I doing wrong. I understand that there is some issue with the datatype but why and what can I do to resolve this?

My C# code:

````
int[] nums = new int[5];

int i = 0;
while (i < 5)
{
    int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    if (Array.Find(nums, num) != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: Number already inputed. Try a different number.");
        continue;
    }
    i++;
}```

Error:
*Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Predicate<int>'    udemy lectures beginner section6 exercise   D:\C# practice\C# practice codes\exercises\udemy lectures beginner section6 exercise\udemy lectures beginner section6 exercise\Program.cs   104 Active*  (line 8)
````

Comment: You probably want `Array.IndexOf(nums, num) != -1`

Comment: `Array.Find` pretty much works the same as Linq's `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault` except that it's not an extension method. So you need to pass it a delegate of `Predicate<T>` signature. 
As the others said, IndexOf does what you want in this usecase. Less tinsel.

Comment: With `System.Linq;` in the using block `if (nums.Contains(num))` is also pretty straight forward for verifying the number entered is contained in the array.

Answer (score 7):

you can create predicate using a lambda syntax

```
var index = Array.Find (nums, n=> n == num); // n == num returns a bool

//array returns a position of a found item in array if item is found. If it is not found returns -1;

if ( index >= 0 )   // if found
{

// or shorter
if ( Array.Find (nums, n => n == num) >= 0 )   // if found
{
...
```

but it is usually used of array of complicated objects. For example if array items were not int, but a class with Id and Name properties you could use it

```
var index=Array.Find (nums, n=> n.Id == num);
```

For a simple array like yours, it's better to use

```
if (Array.IndexOf(nums, num) != -1) // index of found item or -1 if not found
{
...
```

Comment: Thanks. But can you also explain `n=> n== num` . What is it doing? Basically how a simple predicate works?

Edit: Maybe I understood. It is checking for each n in num, whether n is equal to num or not until it is true. Right?

Comment: @Anshuman I  added some explanations to my answer.

Comment: @Anshuman Basically predicate is  a function (or a delegate) that usually returns true or false.